# What are the rough dimensions of the ISS?

Tags: iss, history, dimensions

In about 2014, i was told the ISS was about the size of one American football field.  In American football (not soccer), the field is 100-120 yards long by 53 yards wide.  In 2016, some cub scouts recently said it was over two football fields in size and the ball of light appears bigger.  Is there a short history of its growth in terms of football field size?  Soccer Field size?

Comment: The first google result is http://www.livescience.com/32583-how-big-is-the-international-space-station.html

Comment: No, it's size didn't doubled in 2 years.

Comment: The LiveScience graphic is good, but six years old.

Comment: Which is OK, since the size hasn't changed since then.

Answer (score 4):

Dimensions of the ISS (in real units) at each step of its construction can be found in these documents:

- [On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book volume 1](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~grandajj/ME296M/space.pdf), 2002
- [On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book volume 1](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~grandajj/ME296M/RevAB_Volume%20I%20Signed_updated.pdf), 2008
- [On-Orbit Assembly, Modeling, and Mass Properties Data Book volume 2](http://athena.ecs.csus.edu/~grandajj/ME296M/RevAB_Volume%20II%20Signed_updated.pdf), 2008

I haven't found a more recent edition than 2008.

Converting to football fields is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I didn't know these documents were available in the wild.